# Is it possible to create a custom equation in the group summary in COGNOS version 11

Tags: cognos-11

I’ve created a report in COGNOS which groups all duplicate orders together which works well.

I’m trying to work out if there is a way to do a custom equation within the group summary to total the value for all entries within the group but then minus the first line within the group for a total.

The first entry within the group is the received order all others are extra orders received but are human errors. My hope is to have my report show a value for all the group total and then the group total minus the first value.

The total summary at the end of the report should then give me our final figures.

This way I can work out what we have paid for original orders and then when we have paid for extra unwanted orders. I’m hoping this makes sense.

Comment: Hi aidan, yep you can do that.  Is this in relation to the previous post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776350/cognos-report-for-duplicate-data-only